# Need help understanding this UART to RS485 adapter circuit

Tags: mosfet, uart, rs485

I am trying to understand how this circuit works.

[image]

Below is the explanation provided in the manual I am referring to:

"Receiving data: P_TX is in idle state, which is high level, transistor breakover, RE pin of
SP3485 is low to be active. RO pin begins to receive data from 485AB port.
Sending data: P_TX will get a pull-down level, toggle that sending data. Transistor cut
off, DE pin is high to enable sending. In sending states, if the data sent is “1”,
transistor will turn to breakover which looks like Receiving states, however, the chip is
in high impedance sate, data “1” will still be sending instead of changing to
receiving"

Link to the user manual:
https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/2/29/RS485-CAN-HAT-user-manuakl-en.pdf
Page 7

I would be great if someone can help me understand this circuit.

Comment: Have you read MAX485 data sheet, so do you understand in general how the chip works and how it should be used, to understand the difference to how this board uses it?

Comment: It is poorly written, probably auto-translated from Chinese (that's where all the new electronics is invented!). I agree, easier to look at the MAX485 datasheet which is written properly and then you will understand this. There is not a lot to see in the schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is bad and needs a lot of interpretation. However, here is what it tries to say. Please be aware that English is not my native language, though. ;-)

**Receiving data:**

If P_TX is in the idle state, which is the high level, the transistor conducts producing a low level on RE and DE. This means that the receiver part is enabled (RE = receiver enable, active low) and the driver part is disabled (DE = driver enable, active high). The RO pin produces data as received from the RS485 bus via A and B.

**Sending data:**

For bits of "0", P_TX is low and the transistor switches off producing a high level on RE and DE. This means that the receiver part is disabled and the driver part is enabled. For bits of "1", P_TX is high and the RS485 bus is not driven, as while receiving. The resistors R1, R9, and R10 put the bus in the "1" state, given that no external component changes this.

**Conclusion:**

| Situation | P_TX | Receiver | Driver | Bit on RS485 bus | RO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bus idle | 1 (high) | enabled | disabled | "1" (via resistors) | 1 (high) |
| Receiving "0" | 1 (high) | enabled | disabled | "0" (actively) | 0 (low) |
| Receiving "1" | 1 (high) | enabled | disabled | "1" (via resistors or actively by another component) | 1 (high) |
| Sending "1", other components are idle | 1 (high) | enabled | disabled | "1" (via resistors) | 1 (high) |
| Sending "1", any other component sends "0" | 1 (high) | enabled | disabled | "0" (actively) | 0 (low) |
| Sending "0" | 0 (low) | disabled | enabled | "0" (actively) | undefined (high impedance) |

As shown in the schematic, this circuit is apparently not a real UART-to-RS485 adapter. It does not send the "1" bits actively, but by the provided pull-up and pull-down resistors.

This has at least the disadvantage that depending on the other components on the RS485 bus, "1" bits can be disturbed or overwritten.

However, the advantages are:

- The UART part does not need to control the DE and RE pins separately.
- This adapter can be used in [CAN networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus), which expect "1" bits to recessive. Only "0" bits are dominant.

  *Note: Commonly a CAN module expects to receive the bits from the bus also during sending. For this to happen with this adapter, only DE shall be driven by P_TX. RE shall be enabled (low) all the time.*

The working of the adapter can be changed by using other combinations of the resistors R8, R11, R12, and R13.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing an explanation. So I am using this adapter board to communicate with sensors that use modbus rtu over rs485. Sometimes the sensors are not responding to the host command. Do you think this implementation of the uart-rs485 circuit might be an issue? Should I just use a gpio pin to control the DE and RE pins?

Comment: @ChandrashekharChoudhary Communication can have a multitude of problems. Depending on your actual wiring and circuitry, it _could_ be this specific adapter. However, feel free to post another question on this other issue. Please add enough information and debug results for us to be able to help at all.